# Nesting $ in fraction inside table in latex

Tags: tables

Hello I'm trying to make this latex table but but I have problem in the fraction in second line of table which is that missing `}` or forgetting `$`

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|p{5cm}}
    Metric & Equation & Description \\
    \hline
    Negative Sentiment  & ${NB}_1$ where S= $S_{-1}$ & Absolute number of negative statements about a brand \\ \hline
    Negative Sentiment Ratio & $\frac{X}{$${NB}_1$$}$ & negative comments compared to the total number of statements on the Brand. \\ \hline
    Positive Sentiment & ${NB}_1$ where S= $S_1$ & Absolute number of Positive statements about a brand \\ \hline
    Neutral Sentiment & ${NB}_1$ where S= $S_0$ & Absolute number of Neutral statements about a brand \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!  You can't nest math $s like that.  Just remove the `$$` around the `{NB}_1`.

Comment: Within the inline math environment, you can try removing the `$$...$$`, because, `\frac{}{}` is already encapsulated inside the inline math environment.

Comment: `S= $S_{-1}$`  is completely wrong, the S and = are in text mode, that should be `$S= S_{-1}$`

Answer (score 4):

Math expressions should be contained in one single set of dollars, so

```
$S = S_{-1}$
```

instead of

```
S = $S_{-1}$
```

and

```
$\frac{X}{{NB}_1}$
```

instead of

```
$\frac{X}{$${NB}_1$$}$
```

A double dollor `$$` will cause extra confusion, as it tries to send LaTeX into display math.

I strongly suspect you want `NB` to be upright, you can use `\mathrm{NB}` for this.  (If not and it denotes one symbol, then `\mathit{NB}` would be appropriate.)

Well styled tables should avoid vertical rules and not have too many horizontal ones.  See the documentation of the [`booktabs` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) for a discussion.  I have provided a suggested styling below, also using vertically centered `m` type columns from the `array` package instead of `p`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{ccm{5cm}}
    \toprule
    Metric
    & Equation
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} \\
    \midrule
    Negative Sentiment
    & $\mathrm{NB}_1$ where $S = S_{-1}$
    & Absolute number of negative statements about a brand \\
    \addlinespace
    Negative Sentiment Ratio
    & $\dfrac{X}{\mathrm{NB}_1}$
    & Negative comments compared to the total number of statements on
      the Brand. \\
    \addlinespace
    Positive Sentiment
    & $\mathrm{NB}_1$ where $S = S_1$
    & Absolute number of Positive statements about a brand \\
    \addlinespace
    Neutral Sentiment
    & $\mathrm{NB}_1$ where $S = S_0$
    & Absolute number of Neutral statements about a brand \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for nice answer ... however i would add `\addlinespace` between each rows. just my taste :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thank you.  Yes, `\addlinespace` is better. Code updated.